# How to access  object using dynamic key?

Tags: javascript

How to access an object using a variable as key. Here is my code sample:

```
var o = {"k1": "111", "k2": "222"};
alert(o.k1); //working fine
var key = "k"+1; alert(key); // k1
alert(o.key); //not working
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can access objects like arrays:

```
alert(o[key]);
```

Answer (score 14):

Change the last line to: `alert(o['k1']);` or `alert(o[key]);` where `key` is your dynamically constructed property key.

Remember you can access object's properties with array notation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)