# How can I get this values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have a object that looks like this

```
var object = { id : 1, name : "Test"}
```

And I know that in jQuery I can make an each assuming that I have an array of this object example like this:

```
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (i, value) {
    this.id // gives me the id
    this.name //gives me the name
});
```

Assuming that `id` and `name` are string parameters, how can I get the values??

**UPDATE**

I'm already modified the code, i just want to know if exit's a way to accomplish something like this

```
var aux = 'id'
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (i, value) {
    this.aux // gives me the id
    this+ aux
});
```

Comment: Your object is defined incorrectly it should be var object = { id: 1, name: "Test"}; Exchange the "=" for ":"

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I can't understand your question at all.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense

Comment: I think he's trying to get the keys from the object as well as the values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access  object using dynamic key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921803/how-to-access-object-using-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question, you want to get the object's keys as well as the values?  You can loop over each object in the array to get the keys and values.

```
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function() {
    // Loop though object to get its info
    $.each(this, function(i, v){
        console.log(i+': '+v); // Prints 'id: 1' and 'name: Test'
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**: To use a string as a key in an object, you need to use `[]`.

```
var aux = 'id'
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (i, value) {
    this[aux] // gives me the id
});
```

Comment: @Jorge: You're welcome.  Some advice: when asking a question add as much info as possible at the start, that'll hopefully help us understand it better.  The update you added should have been there from the start.

Comment: i know, sorry but i didn't found a easy thing to explain this

Comment: @Jorge: It's ok, we solved your problem so it's all good. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the object in a wrong way. `:` has to be used instead of `=`, inside object literals.

To finish off, don't omit the closing parenthesis of the `.each` method. You should have noticed this error in the error console (CTRL + SHIFT + J).

```
var object = { id : 1, name : "Test"}

//Example:
var arrayOfObjects = {
    element1: {id:1, name:"test"}
};
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (i, value) {
    value.id // gives me the id
    value.name //gives me the name
}); //<-- Parenthesis!
```

Comment: In `$.each`, `this` is a valid way access the value as well as the `value` parameter.

Comment: thank's for the correction but that's not the answer that i'm looking for

Comment: @Jorge What do you mean with "get the values"? In your code, you're already referring to the values of the elements. If you want to store the retrieved values, use the following code to save data from `arrayOfObjects` to the `remember` array: `var remember=[];$.each(arrayOfObjects, function(){remember.push(this.id)})`

Comment: @Jorge See the code at my previous comment. If that's not what you're looking for, please describe your wishes using words, because your pseudo-code makes no sense, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

value.id and value.name should contain the correct values

Also mind that you should use '{ id: 1, name: "Test"}'

Answer (score 0):

Set up your object to be in an array then loop through that.

```
var object = [{ id : 1, name : "Test"}];

$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (i, obj) {
    obj.id //gives me the id
    obj.name //gives me the name
});
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that he has an array of objects.

Comment: Exactly an array. [] <- array. {} <- object. [{},{},{}] <- array of objects.