# JavaScript Object using . to retrieve values

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access  object using dynamic key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921803/how-to-access-object-using-dynamic-key)

I have multiple select with different options, the later options depend on the earlier choices. So I would like to generate options for later select, I am in the middle of doing this, and I have encountered some problems:

```
function generateOptions(selected) 
  { 
  var jsonObj = ('food':['a','b','c'])
  //able to get selected_value as food  
  var selected_value = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value 
  var options = jsonObj.selected_value  
  }
```

if I do `jsonObj.food`, then I can get output in console `['a','b','c']`. But if I try to use selected_value, then I get `undefined`

So the `.` for retrieving data from an Object only works for absolute values not a `var`? Anybody can help?

Comment: `var jsonObj = ('food':['a','b','c'])` doesn't look like valid JavaScript btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bracket notation for dynamic property names:

```
var options = jsonObj[selected_value];
```