# HTML5 localStorage loading user-input variable

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am creating a HTML5 web app, and it uses localStorage to store its data.
 I would like to know how to see if a variable is set in localStorage, but I would like to have it so that the user inputs the name of the variable to retrieve.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/html5-localstorage-check-if-item-isset

Comment: And: [How to access object using dynamic key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921803/how-to-access-object-using-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isSet(varName) {
    return localStorage.getItem(varName) === null
}

isSet('foo');
```