# Dynamic object properties within a nested AngularJS repeat statement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-properties

I have a repeater within a repeater, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat='x in collection1'>
    <div ng-repeat='y in collection2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is access property y of object x, something like...

```
{{ x.{{y} }}}
```

or

```
{{ x[ {{y}} ] }}
```

...but when I try this I get an error along the lines of..."Syntax Error: Token 'y' is unexpected, expecting [:]."

Is there any way to do something like this with Angular or am I boned here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access  object using dynamic key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921803/how-to-access-object-using-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{{ x[y] }}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cwbr/), though the example is a bit contrived.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually the first thing I'd tried, but it turns out my object wasn't set up like I expected. I was looking for x[firstName] when I needed x.name[first] etc.