# How to select object node by key using variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object called assignments which contains arrays as such;

```
assignments = {
    'version_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'version_2': [6,7,8,9,0],
    'version_3': [3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

if I want to get the values of a particular version I can simply say something like `console.log(assignments.version_2);`

But what if I have an integer set in a variable?  How would I reference the values dynamically.  e.g.

```
var version_id = 2;
console.log(assignments.version_[version_id]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access  object using dynamic key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921803/how-to-access-object-using-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var version_id = 2;
console.log(assignments["version_" + version_id]);
```

Or, if you know you only have to support browsers that have es6, you can do :

```
assignments[`version_${version_id}`]
```

> Es6 template strings make things nicer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @GGO - Added a missing closing brackets - Hope it is good with you

Comment: @Typhoon101 if you know you only have to support browsers that have es6, you cna do `assignments[\`version_${version_id}\`]` -- es6 template strings make things nicer

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
var assignments = {
  'version_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'version_2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  'version_3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
};

var version_id = 2;

console.log(assignments["version_" + version_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
assignments = {
    'version_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'version_2': [6,7,8,9,0],
    'version_3': [3,4,5,6,7]
}
console.log(assignments['version_2'])
```